# Getting auto incremented id's for use in link table

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have three mysql tables set up as shown in the image below.

[image: Relationships between tables]

I am using the middle table to link between the tables either side. The relationship will be that for every entry in the expenses table there will be at least one, but probably more entries in the lines table.

As such I am using a linking table in the middle to keep track of which lines belong to which expenses. However I am not sure how I will go about inserting data into the linking table, as when I insert data into the expenses table or the lines table, the id is auto incremented, as such I will not know what to insert into the linking table.

I am currently using PHP and PDO to do the insertions, and the insertions for the lines table is done using a for loop, so I'm not sure that I can use the last inserted commands. Can anyone advise on how to accomplish this, or am I coming at it in the wrong way?

Comment: look for `last_insert_id()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

juergen, is correct, although I cannot mark his comment as the answer.

```
$conn->lastInsertId();
```

Allowed me to get the id of the last inserted record and then use that in the next insert query.